# AWS Organization SCP Policy Not working for S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-organizations

We were having issues with the AWS Managed Guardrail "Disallow Changes to Encryption Configuration for Amazon S3 Buckets" which has a Deny for "s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration".

This prevented us from adding encryption to a bucket when the bucket is first created.

Ideally, we want to ensure that encryption cannot be deleted once applied.  I modified the policy to Deny deleting the encryption.

However, when disabling encryption, I am not being stopped as expected.   I do see the call in CloudTrail.  I don't understand why the SCP is not preventing the action.

SCP:

```json
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "SandboxTest",
      "Effect": "Deny",
      "Action": [
        "s3:DeleteBucketEncryption"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ],
      "Condition": {
        "ArnNotLike": {
          "aws:PrincipalARN": "arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSControlTowerExecution"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The AWS managed policy is here: [Elective Guardrails - AWS Control Tower](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/controltower/latest/userguide/elective-guardrails.html#log-archive-encryption-enabled)

Thanks!

Comment: Does your user has the role arn:aws:iam::*:role/AWSControlTowerExecution?

Comment: No, the AWSControlTowerExecution role is not associated with any of the users that I've tried with.   When The Deny was for s3:PutEncryptionConfiguration, the SCP worked - unfortunately, that doesn't allow encryption to be applied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no IAM action

```
s3:DeleteBucketEncryption
```

You should not allow buckets to be created without encryption.
But AWS does not have option to enable encryption on bucket creation. You need to enable that after the bucket is created...

- a lambda that triggered by event and adds encryption on newly created buckets
- you only allow users to upload files to buckets with using encryption.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html